# Why does Go-get ask me to pick a branch?

Tags: go, go-get

I want to install mongoDB-driver. When I type this command

```
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```

I got :

```
    #  cd /Users/jiangwei/go/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver; git pull --ff-only
    There is no tracking information for the current branch.
    Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
    See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

    If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

    package go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo: exit status 1
```

Comment: Have you already got this package before?  If so you may need to go to the local directory and run `git pull origin master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you've already checked out that repo into your Go path, and have changed to a non-default branch.  The simplest way to correct it would be to remove that repo, and start from scratch.

```
rm -rf $(go env GOPATH)/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver
```

Of course, this will lose any changes you've made in that repo.